# Wordpress, entity Framework and REST Services integration... POSSIBLE?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, entity-framework, rest

We are moving our sites to WordPress and I have a perplexing problem that I have no idea where to start.

We have a Product Information Manager all stored in SQL Server. I'm looking for a way to integrate products into the WordPress system.

There is a data access layer using entity Framework right now which we are using an asp.net solution right now to access it.

I'm thinking of asking our database developer to create REST services for product information, but I'm not sure how to go about integrating this into WordPress... if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Depending on how many models you need to expose, creating the services may also be trivial if you leverage Web API.

As far as integrating it into WordPress, that's a PHP task, adding pages or editing your theme. So you're going to need to Google some samples on reading JSON or XML in PHP, but that's pretty much the extent of it here. I see no technical limitations.

You can likely start here:
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Cheers.

Comment: Great information! Yeah, I'm going to get our back-end dev to look into Web API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely do that . Once you expose it through REST services or any other SOAP based web service. You can consume thrm from your Wordpress . There are plugins available that might help you.

[Take a look here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/rest)

You can also create your own plugin if you want . I will agree with @MisterJames for other Php stuff and integration that you need to do.